# Flex - How do I scale a mobile device for simulation to fit on my screen?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, simulation, scaling

I'm using Flash builder 4.5 and creating a mobile app for ipad, developing on a macbook pro.

When I run the simulator on desktop the ipad simulation extends below my viewable screen.
(same question for any of the other target platforms - android or blackberry or any ios device)

Is there a way to scale the ipad so that it fits on my screen so I can click on buttons that are along the bottom?

Or is there a way to virtually extend my mac screen?

thanks

steve

Comment: As this has *nothing* to do with flex and everything to do with the dev package for ipad, I have edited the title and tags.

Comment: Sorry, this has everything to do with Flex, I'm using the Flex builder simulator to see my app.  Same question for targeting my app for Android and Blackberry.
There is one partial solution,  - you can rotate your mac screen, for example if your screen resolution is 1024x768, on your rotate you now have 768x1024.  Hold down command-alt when you open your Display preferences and you will get a hidden rotate screen menu.